# React hooks, set return value of a function to state causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, infinite-loop

#### Infinite loop on setting state

I have a array of objects testData, which I want to filter through to get another array with results:

```js
  const testData = [
    {
      time: "2020-01-23T13:16:53+01:00",
      amount: "0.010000000000000000",
      txid: "7b1f6aa63910618913c1c1c2902671d2e4f074a8c77ecfd3d16994a05fbf952d"
    },
    {
      time: "2020-01-31T09:09:13+01:00",
      amount: "-0.012739560000000000",
      txid: "7df38cb2d7538f794d725e4c7e68a3e1e7ee6fd570c3575c53776808c0200145"
    },
    {
      time: "2020-01-31T09:09:24+01:00",
      amount: "0.010000000000000000",
      txid: "db47ba29a36bd2343af287bd75f489c2f39d7ce1edcf24176c555233b0e24286"
    }
  ];
```

Code below works almost good, but I cannot set the return value to a state. When I try to useState in a function it gives me infinite loop.

How can I set state of `historyResult()` return value, so each time when value changes function will call and give me different results.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
  const History = () => {
    const [filteredArray, setFilteredArray] = useState();
      
      // values are coming from Formik. When changed, function should run once more.
      const historyResult = values => {
        let tType = values && values.transactionType; // Checking if the value exists, saving transactionType of values and saving it to variable
        // testData is an array of objects that I want to filter through
        let filteredData = testData.filter(item => {
          const withdraw = item.amount < 0;
          const admission = item.amount > 0;
          // Checking which tType was returned and do instructions
          const type = tType == 1 ? withdraw : tType == 2 ? admission : console.log('no value');
          return type;
        });
        console.log(filteredData); // This log works beautifully - it gives me data I want (array of objects)
        setFilteredArray(filteredData); // I tried to set state on this but got infinite loop. Why's that?
        return filteredData;
      };
  }
```

1. How can I set return value of historyResult to a state without infinite loop?
2. I tried useEffect but I think I got it all wrong and also got infinite loop.

Comment: Try `useEffect(() => { /* setState here */ }, [])`

Comment: Just do setFilteredArray(filteredData), there is no need to return it and you'll be fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use:

`setFilteredArray([...filteredData]);`

Also initialize your state with initial value for e.g. empty array

`const [filteredArray, setFilteredArray] = useState([]);`

You don't need to *return* a value from function. You **never** do it in the React world, instead you just *set* your state with the desired results and use that state where you want. (keep in mind that setting state is an async call)

2. Reason for infinite loop in `useEffect`:

`useEffect` calls every time the component state changes and whenever state changes again `useEffect` gets call and this cycle continues. Here is good [guide](https://www.andreasreiterer.at/react-useeffect-hook-loop/) to prevent infinite loop in the `useEffect`